How can I let higher priority Slurm jobs pass through while not sharing individual CPUs among tasks?
My IT department kindly set me up with a Linux VM with Slurm and I'm learning commands. I'm changing numbers a bit, but let's say there are 2 nodes each with 5 cores/CPUs (I think they're the same here?). I want to run 6 independent iterations of a function, with 3 subtasks each. The first 2 subtasks (a, b) can be run in parallel, but the final one (c) requires the first 2 to finish. For simplicity we can say each subtask takes 1 minute.
Let's also say I start set A with iterations 1-6. But then I realize I would like to run set B iterations 7-14 at a higher priority and immediately start that next. In this situation I would like subtasks a and b for 5 of the iterations in set A to complete during minute 1. For minute 2, I would like subtasks a and b for 5 of the iterations in set B to complete. Minute 3 I would like the final 8 subtaks of B to complete along with 2 subtasks in A. Minute 4 would be the final 6 subtasks of A.
Is this possible? How would I go about this?
A MWE is below, but just starting A when I run the top command, I see some CPU usage is 100% for some processes, and 50% for others. With the 50% processes, there are more total running than number of cores. I would prefer the script finishes tasks and waits for a CPU to become free before starting the next because I would think this would be faster to get iterations finished. In this example though, the runtime was always 2 minutes even at 50%, maybe due to the nature of the stress command? All iterations started and ended at the same time too for some reason.
Command I ran
./test_main.sh
Content of test_main.sh
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf 'out'
mkdir -p 'out/'

for i1 in {1..6}; do #Changed to 7..14 for B
 printf -v i_str "%03d" $i1 #add zero-padding
 sbatch ./test_sub.sh "$i_str"
done

Content of test_sub.sh below. I've tried playing around with --hint=nomultithread, --cpus-per-task=1, and --ntasks-per-node=5. In the srun command I've tried with and without --exclusive.
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name setA   ## name that will show up in the queue. Change for set B
#SBATCH --output slurm-%j.out   ## filename of the output; the %j is equal to jobID
#SBATCH --nodes=2              ## Number of nodes
#SBATCH --oversubscribe    ## Letting multiple jobs run concurrently
#SBATCH --partition=mypartition     ## the partitions to run in (comma separated). 
#SBATCH --nice=10000  ## Change to a smaller value for set B

in_dir=$1

run_s="$SECONDS" #start a timer

work_dir=$PWD
mkdir -p 'out/'$in_dir
cd 'out/'$in_dir

# Save some tracking info
hostname > example.out #always the name of the primary node. Not important to my task though
echo '('`date`')' >> example.out

srun -N1 -n1 --exclusive "$work_dir"/test_sub2.sh 'alpha' &
srun -N1 -n1 --exclusive "$work_dir"/test_sub2.sh 'beta' &
wait #wait for subprocess alpha and beta to finish

echo '('`date`')' >> example.out

# Can now run gamma
srun -N1 -n1 --exclusive "$work_dir"/test_sub2.sh 'gamma' &
wait

# Save additional tracking info after gamma finishes
echo '('`date`')' >> example.out
loop_rt=$( echo " scale = 2; ( "$SECONDS"- "run_s" ) / 60 " | bc )
echo "$loop_rt" >> example.out  #Runtime

The content of test_sub2.sh
#!/bin/bash

greekLtr=$1

hostname > "$greekLtr".out
echo '('`date`')' >> "$greekLtr".out

stress --cpu 1 --timeout 60

echo '('`date`')' >> "$greekLtr".out

In my slurm.conf file under scheduling I have
# SCHEDULING
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU

Pointers to similar questions would also be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I've spent too much time on this and I think I figured out. Instead of trying to rely on 3 srun tasks within a job, I just start up multiple sbatch jobs with 1 srun task each and made them dependent on each other. Some combination of the below worked.
In my slurm.conf file, I changed from CR_CPU to CR_CPU_Memory. For each of the nodes I also added RealMemory=16000, (actual value came from running slurm -C on the head node). As root I then ran
systemctl restart slurmctld
scontrol reconfigure

I modified test_main.sh and added dependencies to other job IDs.
#!/bin/bash

# Set nice level
n_main=1000 #Decrease this for set B
n_dep=$(($n_main - 10))

mkdir -p 'out/'

ltr_ary=('alpha' 'beta' 'gamma')


for i1 in {1..6}; do #Changed to 7..14 for B
 printf -v i_str "%03d" $i1 #add zero-padding
 J_IDS='' #Previous job IDs in format ':42:43'
 i2=0
 for greekLtr in "${ltr_ary[@]}"; do
  i2=$(($i2+1))
  if [ "$i2" -lt "${#ltr_ary[@]}" ]; then
   # Not the last one
   out_txt=`sbatch --nice="$n_main" ./test_sub.sh "$i_str" "$greekLtr"`
  else
   out_txt=`sbatch --nice="$n_dep" --dependency=afterok"$J_IDS" ./test_sub.sh "$i_str" "$greekLtr"`
  fi
  job_ID=${out_txt##* } #get the job ID number after the final space
  J_IDS="$J_IDS"':'"$job_ID"
 done #end loop over greek letters
done #end loop over number iterations

Modified test_sub.sh to
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name setA   ## name that will show up in the queue. Change for set B
#SBATCH --output /home/username/slurmlogs/slurm-%j.out   ## filename of the output; the %j is equal to jobID
#SBATCH --nodes=1              ## Number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1   ## Limiting number of tasks and hence CPU per node
#SBATCH --mem=3000M   ## Don't give all memory to just 1 CPU
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1      ## Each task only needs 1 CPU
#SBATCH --partition=mypartition     ## the partitions to run in (comma separated). 

in_dir=$1
greekLtr=$2

work_dir=$PWD
mkdir -p 'out/'$in_dir
cd 'out/'$in_dir

# Could not figure out how to get SBATCH to not overload CPUs without srun and --exclusive...
srun -N1 -n1 --exclusive --mem-per-cpu=3000M "$work_dir"/test_sub2.sh "$greekLtr" &
wait

I kept test_sub2.sh the same.
I verified this worked as expected by starting set B immediately after set A. After the first minute, I observed in squeue that the B jobs started while remaining A jobs were left in pending. CPU usage seemed maximized without getting split among tasks.
This seems to work, but holding off for a bit on accepting my own answer in case there is a more elegant solution.
